# How to test aioredis with Tornado

Tags: python, testing, redis, tornado

I'm using `Tornado` and `aioredis`. I'd like to test some `aioredis` calls (`set`, `get`, etc) of my `aioredis.create_redis_pool` instance within `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase` class.

I've tried to go through the Internet, but I haven't found how to do that.

Is there a way to simulate `aioredis` calls to a temporary `Redis` database in my `Tornado` tests.

Thank in advance

Comment: Do you want run the tests without actually connecting to Redis?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @xyres.

First of all I'd like create a temporary Redis db, also in memory, which is created at the starting point of my tests and deleted once tests are done. Then, I'd like to simulate a call to one of my API in POST which executes a simple query against this temporary db, for example a `set` of a value and then a `get`.

I don't know what's the best practice for this purpose and I was wondering if it's possible or not

Comment: Somebody has created a library for mocking `aioredis`. Here's the Github repo: https://github.com/kblin/mockaioredis. It doesn't have any documentation but it's similar to [this project](https://github.com/locationlabs/mockredis). You'll also need to have some familiarity with Python's [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look and let you know

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with the added twist of creating my redis connection pool before the `Application` instance, so that it can be shared between requests. I successfully used [testig.redis](https://github.com/tk0miya/testing.redis), which creates a redis instance in a temporary directory. The library is old and not much has happened in it for years, but it seems to work. Anyway, the test looks like this:

```
import functools

import aioredis
import testing.redis
import redis
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from tornado.web import Application

from myapp.base import MyApplication


class TestHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.redis_server = testing.redis.RedisServer()
        self.redis_client = redis.Redis(**self.redis_server.dsn())
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.redis_server.stop()

    def get_app(self) -> Application:
        redis_dsn = self.redis_server.dsn()
        redis = self.io_loop.run_sync(functools.partial(
            aioredis.create_redis_pool, f'redis://{redis_dsn["host"]}:{redis_dsn["port"]}/{redis_dsn["db"]}'
        ))
        return MyApplication(redis)

    def test_client_handler_should_return_200(self):
        self.redis_client.set('val', 'a')
        response = self.fetch('/get-some-redis-data/')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.body, 'a')
```

For completion, the usual (non test) app init looks like this:

```
class MyApplication(Application):
    def __init__(self, redis_connection, *args, **kwargs):
        self.redis_connection = redis_connection
        super().__init__(url_patterns, *args, **kwargs)

async def main():
    redis_connection = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(
        f'redis://{options.redis_host}:{options.redis_port}/{options.redis_db}'
    )
    app = MyApplication(redis_connection)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port, address=options.listen_ips)
    event = tornado.locks.Event()
    await event.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hello @michauwilliam, thanks for your answer! In the meanwhile I've tried another library `mockaioredis` which worked very well in my case. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the library `mockaioredis` which worked very well in my case.

To use it, first of all I've "mock" the `aioredis` with `sys.modules['aioredis'] = mockaioredis` in `<project>/tests/__ini__.py` file.

Secondly I've extended the `tornado.web.Application` and set up a method which initialise a Redis pool:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):

    async def _conf_redis(self) -> None:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.redis = await aioredis.create_redis_pool(address='address',
                                                      password='password',
                                                      loop=loop)
```

Then I've set up the test class like below:

```
import my.web


class TestHandler(AsyncHTTPTestCase):

    @tornado.testing.gen_test
    async def get_app(self):

        app = my.web.Application([...])

        await app._conf_redis()
        self.redis = app.redis

        return app
```

Now it is possible to use Redis normally in any test by using, for example, `self.redis._redis.set(...)` or `self.redis._redis.delete(...)` or `self.redis._redis.hsetnx(...)` or `self.redis._redis.flushdb()`.